# Linq to SQL Group by Controller

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I am trying to learn how to write a sql query to return a count of records then group it by an ID and return it to a list. I have tried a few things and keep getting cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable..etc

What I have tried so far in my repository:

```
    public IQueryable<CHECKLIST> GetAllComplaintsCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Checklists
                .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
                .Select(a => new { Amount = a.Sum(b =>b.MonitorEnteredEmpID), Name = a.Key })
                .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If I change it to a IEnumerable I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Amount, int Name>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

**Question**

Can someone please advise me on what I am doing wrong and how I can return a count of all the checklists by EntereredEMPID?

Comment: public IQueryable<CHECKLIST>  is wrong as your return is a new object with an Amount and name not a checklist object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your method `GetAllComplaintsCount()` is `IQueryable<CHECKLIST>`. But in your query, you create an anonymous type at

```
.Select(a => new { Amount = a.Sum(b =>b.MonitorEnteredEmpID), Name = a.Key })
```

and you try to return a `List<T>` of this anonymous type. So this is cannot be casted into a `IQueryable<CHECKLIST>`.

So I guess you have a class (or struct) called `CHECKLIST` that has properties called `Amount` and `Name` (as you use them in your query). Now, instead of creating instances of an anonymous type, create instances of that `CHECKLIST`:

```
 return _context.Checklists
            .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
            .Select(a => new CHECKLIST { Amount = a.Sum(b =>b.MonitorEnteredEmpID), Name = a.Key });
```

and ommit the `.ToList()` as you want to return an `IQueryable` and not a finished `List`.

Of course, if you don't want to execute the query later but return a enumerated `List`, you need to change the signature of your method to `List<CHECKLIST>` and use `.ToList()` like this:

```
public List<CHECKLIST> GetAllComplaintsCount()
{
    try
    {
        return _context.Checklists
            .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
            .Select(a => new CHECKLIST { Amount = a.Sum(b =>b.MonitorEnteredEmpID), Name = a.Key })
            .ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As you (probably) actually whish to know the *count* of elements with a `MonitorEnteredEmpID`, you may consider a totally different return type. How about a `Dictionary<int, int>` that maps your `MonitorEnteredEmpID` to the element count:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount()
{
    try
    {
        return _context.Checklists
            .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So you can use this like that:

```
Dictionary<int, int> result = GetAllComplaintsCount();
Console.WriteLine("ID        COUNT");
foreach(int id in result.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine($"{id}        {result[id]}");
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you be so kind to give me an example where I can return the count of all the checklist items grouped by MonitorEnteredEmpID? I am also a bit confused on how to do this as, this answer is great and only returns the objects in the checklists I simply just want a results of list with two columns of MonitorEnteredEmpID, and count of MonitorEnteredEmpID.

Comment: @epv I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think this is exactly what my last version does. The keys in the dictionary are the `MonitorEnteredEmpID` and the values are the occurences of these IDs.

Comment: Thank you again! You did understand me correctly, except I don't want to just know one specific ID I want a list of all the IDs with the count related to their checklist. For example, I may have multiple people entering checklist and I want to know the counts of all their entered in checklists.

Comment: @epv Still think I don't know  enough about your table structure and content. Edited my output example, maybe that is what you're looking for. Or are there more than one empID per entry?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ID's they are basically like USERID, Sorry for not explaining well as I am still trying to understand it myself. I actually tried the ToDictionary and I get the error of Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEqualityComparer<int>' because it is not a delegate typ at the g=> g.count line.

Comment: @epv Sorry, but this sounds like a new question. You should include the table definition and the relations in that question and give some example data including example results, so that people understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sounds great, will do.